# importing a CSS file from SCSS/Rails 3.2 w/sass-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, compass-sass, sass

I've got a CSS file in vendor/assets/stylesheets, and I'd like to link to it in my application.css.scss file (or thereabouts). I was hoping that this would just render `@import` plus the asset path:

```
@import asset-path('lionbars.css', stylesheet)
```

But no such luck: I get

```
Invalid CSS after "@import ": expected uri, was "asset-path('lio..."
```

Either I've got the syntax wrong, or it's because [`@import` doesn't accept dynamic strings](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/613), but I'm not sure.

So I see a few options. I can either:

1. Figure out the appropriate syntax, if it's just a syntax issue.
2. Rename my file to application.css.scss.erb and replace other existing asset-path references to `<%= asset_path('random/asset.png') %>`. This makes my syntax highlighter very confused, and probably isn't all that efficient. Otherwise, this works.
3. Rename my css file to `_lionbars.css.scss` and call `@import "lionbars"`. Two reasons I don't want to do this, is #1 generally speaking I don't want to touch vendored code, and #2 there's some IE8 specific stuff in there (`<!--[if IE 8]>blahblah<![endif]-->`) that can't go in an scss file, and I don't want to have to break the file up (and I'd still have to find a solution for the IE8 code and how to include that).

So, I'm hoping that the answer is #1, but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: Option #2 worked great for me, and seems to follow the [coding links to assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets) section in the Rails guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [sass-rails](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails) website is quite clear:

> Sprockets provides some directives that are placed inside of comments called require, require_tree, and require_self. **DO NOT USE THEM IN YOUR SASS/SCSS FILES**.

...but I tried it in both dev and production for straight-up css files and it worked just fine:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * ...
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require lionbars
*/
```

So unless anybody has a better idea, this is what I'm going to do. I did have to move the IE8 specific comment into my layout as Sprockets threw up trying to compile it, but I still find this easier than the alternatives. If you've got a better solution than this though, I'd be glad to hear it! I'm not thrilled about using a solution that's explicitly frowned upon on the sass-rails page.

Answer (score 1):

[sass-rails](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails) features asset helpers like `asset-path`. Otherwise, Sass and Compass don't have any concept of `asset-path`.

Alternitavely, you could use `add_import_path` in your config.rb. [See Compass Configuration Reference](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/)

Comment: Yep, I'm using sass-rails. I mentioned I have other existing asset-path references, and they're working just fine, I'd just like it to work when I'm importing a CSS file too.

Comment: I added the fact that I'm using sass-rails to the title. I ended up using a solution that sass-rails explicitly (emphatically) discourages, but if you think of anything better please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution: `@import 'lionbars'`. Sass-rails customizes the `@import` directive to automatically use the asset pipeline.

Comment: This worked very well for me. Thanks! Much better than 'require' because it allows different SCSS files to share variables, functions, mixins, etc.